# Kendo angular grid add static column while export data in excel angular 4

Tags: excel, angular, grid, export-to-excel, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to export data in excel using following code

```
<kendo-excelexport [data]="excelData" [group]="groups" [filterable]="true" fileName="exceldata.xlsx" #excelexport>
    <kendo-excelexport-column title="title">
        <ng-template kendoExcelExportCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{dataItem.isTrue == 1 ? "title" }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template kendoExcelExportGroupFooterTemplate let-group="group" let-aggregates>
            <span> Total</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template kendoExcelExportFooterTemplate let-column="column">
            <span>Grand Total</span>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-excelexport-column>
</kendo-excelexport>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Excel export does not use column template for formatting value or customizing data, please refer following link for further clarification  https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-known-limitations

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the exported workbook by accessing the generated options, and modifying them as necessary:

[DOCS AND EXAMPLE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/#toc-workbook-customization)

You can customize both the appearance and value of each cell based on some custom logic.

Comment: Thanks @topalkata, we can do it in that way but kendo excel export have some own limitation to use kendoExcelExportCellTemplate.